# Why can't make dumps of MySQL DB even though I have ALL privileges?

Tags: mysql, sql, permissions

Just wondering, why I can't make dumps of database even though I have `ALL PRIVILEGES` granted.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for me@%                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `me`@`%`                           |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `me`.* TO `me`@`%`               |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

When trying

```bash
mysqldump --single-transaction --skip-add-locks --routines --triggers --column-statistics=FALSE --set-gtid-purged=OFF --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS --host=$MYSQL_HOST --port=$MYSQL_PORT $MYSQL_DATABASE > test.sql
```

it is throwing an error

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'FLUSH TABLES': Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD or FLUSH_TABLES privilege(s) for this operation (1227)
```

Doesn't `ALL` mean `ALL` (therefore, it will also give `RELOAD` and `FLUSH_TABLES` privilege)?

Well, I made sure that this is the good database I'm connecting to (it is). Double checked my permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PROCESS` is a global privilege. Your `me` user does not have this privilege as you have only granted all privileges on your `me` database, which does not grant global privileges.

You can grant the global privilege with

```sql
GRANT PROCESS TO `me`@`%`
```

This however will grant your `me` user access to information about all databases and all tables on the database server, which may not be what you want.

Instead of granting this privilege, you can thus use the `--no-tablespaces` option on your `mysqldump` command. While this will cause tablespaces to not be dumped, your user does not require the global `PROCESS` privilege anymore.

To quote [the `mysqldump` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html):

> `mysqldump` requires at least the `SELECT` privilege for dumped tables, `SHOW VIEW` for dumped views, `TRIGGER` for dumped triggers, `LOCK TABLES` if the `--single-transaction` option is not used, and (as of MySQL 8.0.21) `PROCESS` if the `--no-tablespaces` option is not used. Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.

Comment: Is `RELOAD` or `FLUSH_TABLES` also global privilege?

Comment: The `CREATE USER, FILE, PROCESS, RELOAD, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE, SHOW DATABASES, SHUTDOWN`, and `SUPER` privileges are administrative and can only be granted globally.